# field name in forms must match model attribute names in RAILS 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

Does Rails always map out the model attribute name using `name="example"` in the form?

this means that the name attribute on a form field has always strictly match the db column name that the ActiveRecord model is mapped to?

for example, in my code

```
<%= form_for(@property, :url => landlord_properties_path(current_landlord),:html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' , object: f.object %>
<div class="form-group selection property type">

  <%= f.text_field :locality, 'name'=>"locality" %>
  <%= f.text_field :country, 'name'=>"administrative_area_level_1" %>

  <%= f.submit "add", class: "btn btn-s-md btn-success pull-right"  %>

  <% end %>
```

I have an attribute in my AR called :locality that matches my db column name :locality

I also have another attribute named :country, but because in the form, the name is being overridden to `'name'=>"administrative_area_level_1"` it seems like the data isnt being passed through to AR

I am overriding the name because I am using Geocomplete, and those name fields are used to make google map api calls. `'name'=>"administrative_area_level_1"` is really not convenient to have in a database.

here is my strong parameter method for property

```
  def property_params
       params.permit(:postal_code,:place_id,:country,:locality)
  end
```

this currently does not work, no value is passed into :country

if i add `:administrative_area_level_1` to params.permit, then rails complains

```
unknown attribute: administrative_area_level_1
```

which I am guessing is because I dont have it in my db.

Is there a way for me to map `name= administrative_area_level_1` field to :country column  in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your model you can define the following method:

```
def administrative_area_level_1=(input)
  self.country = input # Or do what ever you want with the input to map it to country
end
```